# Numbers of user models I should use using passport local?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, mongoose-schema, passport-local

I am working on my first real life application. It has several types of users: 1. Normal, 2. Admin and a Single Super.

I am in dilemma choosing between:

1. Creating a mongoose string enum field to hold each of these levels (1 model for all users)
2. Creating two different models, one for users one for admin + Supers (2 different models)

EDIT1:

Here is the whole app.js:

```
var express   = require('express'),
    path      = require('path'),
    mongoose  = require('mongoose'),
    app       = express(),
    passport  = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');


var indexRoutes = require(path.join( __dirname, "routes" )),
    User        = require(path.join( __dirname, "models", "user"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/**-**");

// Passport configuration.
app.use(require("express-session")({
  secret: "Secret!",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


app.use("/", indexRoutes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server has started!");
});
```

Comment: What do the models look like? Do the fields overlap? I'd probably use one model and just have a type field that cannot be edited by users.

Comment: Fields overlap a bit, not too much, users -> students, admins -> companies, super user -> us

Comment: my question is can you actually have two models when using passport, passport-local and passport-local-mongoose?

Comment: yes you can have different models

Comment: how?, I have `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());` in app.js won't they break if I use a different model for login?

Comment: I have added my app.js on the top have a look

Comment: where is your User.Authenticate() ,  User.SerializeUser() and User.DeserializeUser() defined? Can i see them?

Comment: I did not build them, I just did `User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)` using the passport-local-mongoose